# Oracle trigger that update record after insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want update book ant set `amount-1`, when after insert record to `sell` table.

```
create table book (
id number(3) not null, 
name varchar(20),
author varchar(12),
amount number(3) not null,
constraint book_pk primary key(id)
);

create table sell (
id number(3) not null, 
date varchar(20),
book_id number(3),
constraint sell_pk primary key(id)
);
```

I want after insert to table sell record update book table  amount-1;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGER changes_amount_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON sell 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

UPDATE BOOK SET amount = amount-1 WHERE id = book_id

END;
```

I not know how to get inserted record book id, to update this record in book table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Model Assumptions:**

I am assuming you will register transactions by changing the data in the `SELL` table through `INSERT` DML SQL operations.  This is also supported by your set up of a DML trigger on `SELL` to pass its changes as SALES information to the `BOOK` table.  This is workable.

By accident, I tried setting up the trigger a little differently and I'd like to suggest a different approach:

**Consider possibly** working in the opposite direction: Change book quantities directly on the `BOOK` table, so a single purchase of book_id = 5 would handle queries that could:

```
    UPDATE book SET amount = amount -1
     WHERE id = 5;  COMMIT;
```

Restocking would mean increasing the quantity of available books
by incrementing the `AMOUNT` value instead.

There are a few additional changes that might tighten up this two-table design and protect the integrity of the data within them for the longer term:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    id number(3) not null, 
    name varchar(20),
    author varchar(12),
    amount number(3) not null,
    CONSTRAINT book_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );


ALTER TABLE book
   ADD CONSTRAINT book_amt_ck CHECK (amount > 0);

ALTER TABLE book
   ENABLE CONSTRAINT book_amt_ck;
```

To prevent negative book amount (quantity) values, a TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINT would prevent the entry of values by means of arithmetic errors in DML operations such as:

```
    UPDATE book SET amount := amount - 1
```

In the example above, there is no control over decrementing the book inventory even if the quantity on hand has reached 0.  Check out a few references on [TABLE CHECK CONSTRAINTS](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php) to get a better understanding of what it can do for specific design situations.

**Here are some design suggestions for the trigger:**

1. Changes in book quantities should be the only triggering data element that affects the `SELL` table.
2. The trigger should account for changes in book quantities > 1.

   ```
       CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_after_update
           AFTER UPDATE
              ON book
             FOR EACH ROW

           DECLARE
             v_amount   number;

           BEGIN

           IF (:new.amount < :old.amount ) THEN

              FOR v_amount in  1 .. (:old.amount - :new.amount)
              LOOP
                 INSERT INTO sell (id, date, book_id)
                 VALUES (sell_seq.nextval, sysdate, :new.id);

                 COMMIT;

              END LOOP;

           END IF;

       END;
   ```

For more information on triggers and their design, check a few instances to get a better understanding of how they are designed and set up.

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE sell_seq
       MINVALUE 1
       START WITH 1
       INCREMENT BY 1
       CACHE 20;
```

We needed a sequence to populate the primary key/index of the `SELL` table.  [Oracle Sequences](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) are useful for this purpose.

By watching the table changes with a trigger on the `BOOK` table, you can use the built in references which already exist when a table trigger fires.  For example, `BOOK.ID` does not require an additional query because a trigger automatically is made aware of the beginning and ending value of each trigger monitored record.

Some useful discussions on triggers are discussed in [more detail](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php) through an Internet search.

**Setting Up a Foreign Key Relationship**

Although the trigger will probably keep this relation clean, a Foreign Key relation between elements `BOOK.ID` and `SELL.BOOK_ID` would be good, otherwise queries on Sales transactions may yield book sales without any descriptive production information.  The following is [a reference on Foreign Keys](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php) and their use.

```
CREATE TABLE sell (
    id number(3) not null, 
    date varchar(20),
    book_id number(3)
    );


ALTER TABLE table_name
   ADD CONSTRAINT sell_fk
   FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
   REFERENCES book(id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER changes_amount_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON sell 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     UPDATE BOOK SET amount = amount-1 WHERE id = :new.book_id;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have records in sell table and want to update the amount in book table ?
if this is your case you can update your book.amount as following:

```
update book  b
set b.amount = b.amount - (select count(*) from sell s where b.id = s.book_id);
```

Comment: I must use server side trigger